# Motor that has at least 50in-lbs of torque and 200RPM

Tags: motor, torque

I need a motor that has at least 50in-lbs of torque and turns 200 times in one minute (200RPM)

[THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GPV1C8C) screw driver has inside the motor that I need.

[image]

I do not want to buy the electric screwdriver I posted on the link because **I only need the motor**.

When searching for DC motors on the internet I am not able to find a motor with 50in-lbs of torque. 
50 in-lbs = 6 Nm = 57 kg-cm

What could I be doing wrong? Do I have to search with a different criteria? The motor that I have found with most torque and that size is [THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RK8WR9W) one:

---

[image]

That motor has 1/3 the torque of the electric screwdriver. It also spins 4 times slower (50 RPM). The price is doubled. **Am I reading the specs wrong?** Where can I find a motor that has 50in-lbs of torque and is not that slow? **What do I have to search for?**

Comment: Find a motor of appropriate power ( = torque * speed), and use gears to convert its torque to the torque you need.

Comment: Neither of those are motors. They are motor + gearbox. The motors will run much faster than 200 RPM. The motor you have photographed looks like a higher quality unit than the motors typical in mass-produced electrical items so double the cost seems reasonable.

Comment: What motor should I buy then? Any link will be helpful.

Comment: Specific product recommendations are off topic; we're not a shopping site.

Comment: buying the screwdriver may be the most economical solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do I have to search for?

"Gearmotor" or "gear motor" are the most likely search terms. Products like the one pictured are made in huge quantities and are made with gear motors that are likely either designed and built by the product manufacturer or designed and manufactured under contract with them by another company. There are relatively few gear motors like that available to individual buyers.

If you only need one or a few motors, buying the product for the motor may be the best option. If you need a few more and have already purchased that item and taken it apart, try to figure out if the motor was manufactured by another company, try searching using that company name. You may that someone is selling some excess stock of that company.

You may be able to find a small reduction gear to mate up to a high-speed motor, but that seems unlikely. Sometimes reduction gears are constructed inside the housing of a product like the one pictured. You might be able to do that, but you should compare what is required to do that with purchasing the pictured product.

> Am I reading the specs wrong?

Possibly yes. If you look carefully, you will see that 200 RPM is the no-load speed. I didn't see what speed corresponds to 44 in.-lbs. of torque, but it is probably not close to 200 RPM and possibly closer to stall than 200 RPM.